# Как получить управление по нажатию на элемент foreground сервиса?

Tags: java, android

Есть foreground сервис, который запускается при запуске приложения в onResume() MainActivity

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(PedometerActivity.this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

        mPedometerService = new Intent(PedometerActivity.this, PedometerService.class);
        startService(mPedometerService);
    }
```

Сам кастомный сервис:

```
public class PedometerService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, PedometerActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        Notification notification;
        notification = builder.build();

        notification.contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.pedometer_service);
        startForeground(777, notification);

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

и его отображаемый вид:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/azure"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagenotileft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagenotileft"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:text="@string/today_distance"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="13250m"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/state"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@mipmap/green_foot"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Как сделать так (предполагаю, что как-то нужно привязать интент), чтобы по нажатию на правый ImageView (state) была возможность получать управление и выполнять какие-то действия? Сейчас при нажатии на сервис запускается приложение, а надо, чтобы при нажатии именно на ImageView выполнялось действие, а если кликнули в другом месте, то запускать активити.

Comment: нельзя кликнуть отдельно по картинке и отдельно по `TextView`. можете добавить `addAction()` к `Notification.Builder` и там обработать нужные вам `PendingIntent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно получить RemoteViews для Notification сервиса и назначить широковещательного слушателя для моего ImageView. Проблема состояла в том, что слушателя также нужно объявить в манифесте, а я, как начинающий, об этом не знал. Поэтому код и не работал должным образом.

В onStartCommand() сервиса добавляем:

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.pedometer_service);
Intent buttonStateIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationStateButtonHandler.class);
buttonStateIntent.putExtra("action", "close");

PendingIntent buttonClosePendingIntent = pendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, buttonStateIntent, 0);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.state, buttonClosePendingIntent);

notification.contentView = remoteViews;
```

Далее в широковещательном слушателе меняем состояние картинки и всей программы вцелом, отправив сервису интент с нужными данными:

```
public class NotificationStateButtonHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Intent mPedometerService;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Change pedometer state (on to off, or off to on)
    if (PedometerService.isListenAccelerometer() == false) {
        SendIntentToService(context, PedometerService.ACCELEROMETER_ON);
    } else {
        SendIntentToService(context, PedometerService.ACCELEROMETER_OFF);
    }
}

// Create new intent and send it to service for transmitting in service new value of
// accelerometer listener (on or off)
private void SendIntentToService(Context context, int lister_state) {
    mPedometerService = new Intent(context, PedometerService.class);
    mPedometerService.putExtra(PedometerService.ACCELEROMETER_KEY, lister_state);
    context.startService(mPedometerService);
}
}
```

Ну и не забыть все это дело объявить в манифесте:

```
  <receiver 
        android:name="NotificationStateButtonHandler" >
  </receiver>
```